# how to get all compiled queries in dataform using cli?

Tags: dataform

I want to get all compiled dataform sql queries via cli.
when I execute

```html
dataform compile
```

it returns:

```
    datasetname.tablename1 [table]
    .
    .
```

but I want to get all sql queries of my project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a flag for the compile to get the json: `dataform compile --json`

You can then output this into a json file and then query it further using the `jq` tool.

`dataform compile --json > result.json`

---

For example, if you want to list all the queries, you could do this:

`jq .tables | .[] | .query' result.json`

---

If you want to query a specific table, then assuming the table name is "tbl1":

`jq '.tables | .[] | select(.target.name == "tbl1") | .query' result.json`.

---

Hope that helps!